# tabula-pyのlines must be orthogonal, vertical and horizontalに関して

Tags: python

pythonのtabula-pyにてPDFファイルを解析すると下記エラーが表示されます。

```
page_tables = tabula.read_pdf(pdffile, pages="all", silent=True)
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: lines must be orthogonal, vertical and horizontal
        at technology.tabula.Ruling.intersectionPoint(Ruling.java:214)
        at technology.tabula.Ruling.findIntersections(Ruling.java:378)
        at technology.tabula.extractors.SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm.findCells(SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm.java:134)
        at technology.tabula.extractors.SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm.extract(SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm.java:63)
        at technology.tabula.extractors.SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm.extract(SpreadsheetExtractionAlgorithm.java:41)
        at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp$TableExtractor.extractTablesSpreadsheet(CommandLineApp.java:452)
        at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp$TableExtractor.extractTables(CommandLineApp.java:410)
        at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp.extractFile(CommandLineApp.java:180)
        at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp.extractFileTables(CommandLineApp.java:124)
        at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp.extractTables(CommandLineApp.java:106)
        at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp.main(CommandLineApp.java:76)
```

エラーの原因と対処方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。